# Microsoft graph batch requests

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have the following requirement :

1. create an office 365 unified group
2. add members to it
3. add each of the members to the accepted senders list of the group
4. fetch the following IDS for local storage (sql server)

   - The group ID
   - The group's main thread ID
   - The group's main planner plan ID
   - The group's main planner bucket ID

Can I batch this using the following : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching

Answer (score 0):

You can use dependsOn to sequence requests as specific order but it will be easier to run them as separated batches, one after another.

1. Create group
2. Add members
3. ...

For adding users in a batch try json like this (replace id's with group and userIds):

```
`
    {
      "requests": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "method": "POST",
          "url": "/v1.0/groups/{id}/members/$ref"
          "body": {
              "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}"
            }
        }
        {
          "id": "2",
          "method": "POST",
          "url": "/v1.0/groups/{id}/members/$ref"
          "body": {
              "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}"
            }
        }
      ]
    }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I am doing it, I have a request object (in the JSON batch) for each api request.
Logically, I can't proceed with any of my requests without having created the group. So the first one will be the POST to the groups endpoint.
What I would like is a way for subsequent requests to use the newly created group ID to, for example, add members.

Is that doable in the same batch (same JSON batch object)?
If yes, how?